# Are there any "hacks" to be able to return a long from main()?

Tags: c#, algorithm

According to MSDN, the only return values of `main()` can be `void` or `int`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx.

According to the programming challenge I'm attempting,

> This document specifies the intended operation of the csLogic.exe
>   program
>
> csLogic [equation] [parameter1] [parameter2] [parameter3] ...
>
> example usage: csLogic.exe ~1^(2~&3) 0x3FFE 0x2FCE 0xFCC1
>
> Returns the value: 4926 (0x133E)
>
> [...]
>
> Parameters are up to 64 bit values
>
> [...]

Is there any way to make my `main()` return 64-bit values? Or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but its not a C# limitation but a [WinAPI limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx), the exit code of a process can only be a 32 bit number no matter what language it is programed in.

As a "Way around it" we need more details of your requirements, does your challenge require you use the return code of the program? Could you just output the result to `Console.Write(` or to an output file?